# Main class in Java. What is being called?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

This is the code:

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Picture().edit();
    }
}
```

Why are there brackets infront of Picture?

There is a Picture class, which has an edit method, but the picture class also has a Picture method.

What is going on here?

Is the Picture class being created, which calls its picture method, while also calling the edit method aswell?

Thanks

Comment: That's based on syntax .. java syntax. there's a constructor for Picture that takes no args. You see code like this alot. e.g i can say (new String()).toString()

Comment: This is explained by any Java tutorial, and in case you're not familiar with the English terminology, `Picture` has parentheses, not brackets (the brackets are after `String`), and they are after `Picture`, not before.

Comment: Please review more Java material, to grok

Comment: You create a new object Pciture, and call the edit method of that class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Picture()` is instantiating a new picture object, which will call it's constructor. It's `.edit();` is a method which it calls right away.

Since `edit()` is not static, it needs to be run from an instantiated class.

It's the same as typing

```
Picture pic = new Picture();
pic.edit();
```

The only difference is `pic` can be reused later without having to instantiate and construct a new `Picture` object every time.

Calling it by `new Picture().edit();` is good for a short-handed way of doing a one off call on something as garbage collection will take care once it's finished executing.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, they all make sense after considering the rest of the code. This particular response is my favourite.

Comment: Your language is inexact and confusing.  While I agree that the code `new Picture()` causes the instantiation of a new object, you appear to suggest that the new picture object will call its own constructor.  Strictly speaking, the constructor creates the initial state of the new object and it is not proper to speak of the object existing in a consistent state before the constructor has completed executing.  Therefore, "a new object cannot call its own constructor."

Comment: I'm trying to convey this in a java 101 terms, not split hairs over minor semantics. In layman's terms, `new Picture()` calls the constructor as `Picture()` does not happen until `new Picture()`. Based on OP's understanding of Java, "the constructor creates the initial state of the new object and it is not proper to speak of the object existing in a consistent state before the constructor has completed executing." probably isn't going to mean a thing. Feel free to edit the answer as you see fit

Answer (score 3):

All you're doing here is creating a `Picture` instance via an argument-less (perhaps default) constructor. Subsequently, you call the `edit()` method on the instance you just created. Since you're not storing the `Picture` instance anywhere, it is eligible for garbage collection directly after the method call is complete.

For all practical purposes, you could have written your code as

```
Picture picture = new Picture();

picture.edit();
```

Note that a `Picture` *method* is not involved anywhere in your snippet. There is a difference between [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) and [methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

---

> Why are there brackets infront of Picture?

This is simply the syntax of object creation in Java. It's clear that if the `Picture` constructor took some argument, then we would definitely need those brackets:

```
new Picture(someArg)
```

But the fact that we even need the brackets with a 0-arg constructor is purely a language design decision. I believe in a language like Scala (which also runs on the JVM) you can get away without using the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling Picture class constructor and then edit() function. If there is a function named as Picture its never called. You may call it if want to.

```
Picture pic = new Picture();
pic.edit(); // call edit function

Picture pic = new Picture();
pic.Picture(); // call picture function
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the constructor, it creates a new Picture object. If there were any arguments to the constructor, they would go inside the parenthesis.

```
new Picture()
```

Here we call the edit method on the newly created picture object:

```
new Picture().edit();
```

Since the Picture object is not saved it is lost afterwards. If you only want to make this one method call, it is probably ok.